# Mod_Rewrite - Filtering by file type

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Wordpress blog whose directory structure contains a "sermons" folder. This directory has mp3 and pdf files relative to a given sermon.

I also now have a friendly url for sermons called "sermons" This obviously causes a problem.

Is there a way to filter the results so that if the requested file is a pdf or mp3 it accesses the file system, but other wise it's processed by the rules in htaccess that govern other WordPress pages?

Here is what I currently have:

```
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sermons/(.+)/*\.(mp3|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Post your current htaccess rules in the question.

Comment: The above stopped working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going based off of assumption since you did not post your current code. You should be able to use this at the top of your other rules.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sermons/(.+)/*\.(mp3|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
```

Comment: I think this is close, but what the directory structure has subfolders like this: "sermons/BibleStudies/" and "sermons/preacher1". So I need the rule to take into consideration the presence of subfolders. Does this make sense?

Comment: See when asking a question you have to include **all** of that info as we can't read minds and you won't get your question answered. :)  I have updated the answer to include subfolders.

Comment: I realized that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It almost works. I have Wordpress pages that have this taxonomy: /sermons/speakers/ or /sermons/conferences/. They are being returned not found. Which I am guessing is related to this rule. Is there a tweak I can apply?

Comment: Panama Jack, can you look at the new problem?